# Using $size and $addToSet to compare multiple arrays from the same cluster

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is an example of the kind of documents I'm querying:

**INPUT:**

```
}
    "_id": ObjectId("2786872873872"),
    "data_shop" : {
        "records_data" : [
            {
                "artist_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "BEYONCE",
                    },
                ],
                "album_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "COUNTDOWN",
                    }
                ],
                "qty" : [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2,
                    3
                ]
            },
            {
                "artist_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "MUSE",
                    },
                ],
                "album_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "THE RESISTANCE",
                    }
                ],
                "qty" : [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    3
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
}
}
    "_id": ObjectId("2786872855555"),
    "data_shop" : {
        "records_data" : [
            {
                "artist_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "MAC MILLER",
                    },
                ],
                "album_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "SWIMMING",
                    }
                ],
                "qty" : [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                ]
            },
            {
                "artist_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "DAFT PUNK",
                    },
                ],
                "album_name" : [
                    {
                        "val" : "RANDOM ACCESS MEMORIES",
                    }
                ],
                "qty" : [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

**What I've done so far:**

I'm trying to use both $size and $addtoSet in order to return the ObjectIds that have repeated numbers in the **qty** field. As you can see, only the first ObjectId has a repeated number (3) in the qty field.
This is what I've done so far:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {"data_shop.records_data.qty.1": {$lte: 1}}},
        {
            $project: {Album_Cluster:"$data_shop.records_data"}
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$Album_Cluster"
        },
        {
            $project: {qty: "$Album_Cluster.qty"},
        },
        {
            $project: {qty_size: {$size: "$qty"}, qty:1}
        },
        { $match: {"qty_size.1": {$exists: false}, qty_size: {$gt: 1} }},
        {$group:
            {_id: "$_id",
            totalSize: {$push: "$qty_size"},
            realSize: {$addToSet: "$qty"},
            }
        },
    ],
    {allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

And this is the result of the query above, in order to check the functionality of the query:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("2786872873872"), "totalSize": [4, 5], "realSize":[[0, 1, 2, 3]]}
{"_id":ObjectId("2786872855555"), "totalSize": [4, 5], "realSize":[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]}
```

I'm a little bit stuck at this part since I want to compare the total size of each array versus the real size of the array (by real size I mean non-repeating numbers)

**OUTPUT**

This is how the output of the query should look like:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("2786872873872"), "isRepeating": true}
{"_id":ObjectId("2786872855555"), "isRepeating": false}
```

**EDIT:**
I've improved my query in order to get this output schema:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {"data_shop.records_data.qty.1": {$lte: 1}}},
        {
            $project: {Album_Cluster:"$data_shop.records_data"}
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$Album_Cluster"
        },
        {
            $project: {qty: "$Album_Cluster.qty"},
        },
        {
            $project: {qty_size: {$size: "$qty"}, qty:1}
        },
        {$group:
            {
            _id: "$_id",
            totalSize: {$addToSet: "$qty_size"},
            realSize: {$addToSet: "$qty"},
            }
        },
        {$unwind: "$realSize"},
        {
            $project: 
            {
                totalSize:1,
                real_count: {$size: "$realSize"}
            }
        },
        {$unwind: "$totalSize"},
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                total_size: {$addToSet: "$totalSize"},
                real_size: {$addToSet: "$real_count"}
            }
        },
    ],
    {allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

And now I'm getting this as my output:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("2786872873872"), "total_size": [4, 5], "real_size":[4]}
{"_id":ObjectId("2786872855555"), "total_size": [4, 5], "real_size":[5, 4]}
```

Now my question is, does `$in` allow me to validate that [4, 5] is valid in [5, 4] so my output will be `isRepeating = false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altought you can achieve this with a stack og unwind / group stages, it can be very expensive in resources consumption.
Unfortunaltely, the $addToSet oerator in available only in $group stage.

But... There's a trick, with the [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator.

> $setUnion performs set operation on arrays, treating arrays as sets. If an array contains duplicate entries, $setUnion ignores the duplicate entries.

Knowing this, performing a $setUnion on your qty array, without any other array, will just... remove the duplicates.

Here's a implementation of this approach, using only 2 project stages

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "data_shop.records_data": {
        $map: {
          input: "$data_shop.records_data",
          as: "data",
          in: {
            qty_size: {
              $size: "$$data.qty"
            },
            qty_size_unique: {
              $size: {
                $setUnion: [
                  "$$data.qty"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      isRepeating: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$data_shop.records_data.qty_size",
              "$data_shop.records_data.qty_size_unique"
            ]
          },
          then: false,
          else: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It will return the expected output :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "isRepeating": true
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "isRepeating": false
  }
]
```